# EventStore & RavenDB Persistence JsonReaderException

Tags: c#, ravendb, cqrs, event-sourcing, neventstore

Trying to wire up [JOliver's EventStore](https://github.com/joliver/EventStore) with [RavenDB](http://ravendb.net) and hit a snag. 
I created a new DB in Raven called RavenEventStore.

The following is my wireup;

```
return Wireup.Init()
           .UsingRavenPersistence("RavenEventStore")
             .UsingAsynchronousDispatchScheduler()
                .DispatchTo(new DelegateMessageDispatcher(DispatchCommit))
           .Build();
```

When the Wireup.Init() is called, this exception is occuring on the RavenDb side;

> Url: "/indexes/RavenCommitByDate" Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value:  . Line 1, position 1.
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue(Char currentChar) in d:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\JsonTextReader.cs:line 699
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadInternal() in d:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\JsonTextReader.cs:line 499
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.ReadForType(JsonReader reader, Type t, JsonConverter propertyConverter) in d:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:line 1072
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType) in d:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:line 118
>      at Raven.Database.Extensions.HttpExtensions.ReadJsonObject[T](IHttpContext context) in c:\Builds\raven\Raven.Database\Extensions\HttpExtensions.cs:line 57
>      at Raven.Database.Server.Responders.Index.Put(IHttpContext context, String index) in c:\Builds\raven\Raven.Database\Server\Responders\Index.cs:line 64
>      at Raven.Database.Server.Responders.Index.Respond(IHttpContext context) in c:\Builds\raven\Raven.Database\Server\Responders\Index.cs:line 49
>      at Raven.Database.Server.HttpServer.DispatchRequest(IHttpContext ctx) in c:\Builds\raven\Raven.Database\Server\HttpServer.cs:line 477
>      at Raven.Database.Server.HttpServer.HandleActualRequest(IHttpContext ctx) in c:\Builds\raven\Raven.Database\Server\HttpServer.cs:line 259

I can see the exception in the RavenDB log as well;

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: . Line 1, position 1.   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue(Char currentChar) in d:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\JsonTextReader.cs:line 699 at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadInternal() in d:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\JsonTextReader.cs:line 499 at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.ReadForType(JsonReader reader, Type t, JsonConverter propertyConverter) in d:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:line 1072 at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType) in d:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:line 118 at Raven.Database.Extensions.HttpExtensions.ReadJsonObject[T](IHttpContext context) in c:\Builds\raven\Raven.Database\Extensions\HttpExtensions.cs:line 57 at Raven.Database.Server.Responders.Index.Put(IHttpContext context, String index) in c:\Builds\raven\Raven.Database\Server\Responders\Index.cs:line 64 at Raven.Database.Server.Responders.Index.Respond(IHttpContext context) in c:\Builds\raven\Raven.Database\Server\Responders\Index.cs:line 49 at Raven.Database.Server.HttpServer.DispatchRequest(IHttpContext ctx) in c:\Builds\raven\Raven.Database\Server\HttpServer.cs:line 477 at Raven.Database.Server.HttpServer.HandleActualRequest(IHttpContext ctx) in c:\Builds\raven\Raven.Database\Server\HttpServer.cs:line 259
```

I have attempted to eliminate all possibilities by removing the UsingAsynchronousDispatchScheduler() method as well and incur the same error.
The code I am using is strictly from the Example located here: 
https://github.com/joliver/EventStore/blob/master/doc/EventStore.Example/MainProgram.cs

Has anyone experienced this? Have failed to find anything on Google as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ryan,
You are using an older server (pre 888) with a new client (888 or later)

Comment: Perfect. I was using build 616. Updated to 800 just to test and had the same issue but then took the next step to 888 as suggested and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may be similar to this one:
[EventStore + RavenDB, not deserializing correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9295503/eventstore-ravendb-not-deserializing-correct)

Also, I would definitely recommend using a custom build against Raven build 888 (or later) as Oren has suggested until I can get a new release out against a newer version of Raven.

Comment: Updating the RavenDb per Ayende's suggestion and that solved the problem. I am currently using EventStore version 3.0.11326.44 and all seems to be well.